How to Track YouTube Video Likes, Subscriptions, and Watch Time in an App for Rewarding Users?
I’m developing an app where users can watch YouTube videos, like, subscribe to a channel, and earn rewards (cash or prizes) for doing so. The goal is to generate views, watch time, likes, and subscriptions for my client’s YouTube channel. However, I’m unsure how to track whether a user has actually liked the video, subscribed to the channel, and how much of the video they have watched.
Is there any way to track these specific actions (like, subscribe, watch time) from within my app? Can the YouTube API help with this, or is there any other method to confirm that users have completed these actions?
I am using flutter at Front end and Supabase for backend

I do not remember anything concerning watch time but for likes and subscriptions respectively YouTube Data API v3 Subscriptions: list and Videos: getRating endpoints. Web-scraping with the credentials of people would work but does not look smooth and secure for the end-user.
